# Youtube video duration to Django model

Tags: python, django, video, youtube

Which is easiest way to get info from youtube video and save in to database?

For example I want get duration from youtube video

my model:

```
class Video(models.Model):

    video_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="title")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    #duration = models.CharField(max_length=10 , default=video_duration)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey("VideoCategory")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    """
    My idea:

    def get_video_duration():

        xml = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + video_id
        open xml
        parse
        s = take duration from xml in seconds

        import datetime

        video_duration = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=s)) in h:m:s

    """


    def __str__(self):

        return self.title
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Edit:

Thank you for answers , so I tried method with json but a I get error video_duration is not defined

```
class Video(models.Model):

video_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="title")
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
duration = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=video_duration)
views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
category = models.ForeignKey("VideoCategory")
tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def video_duration():

    h = httplib2.Http()
    url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%sv=2&alt=json" % video_id
    respose = h.request(url)
    res = json.loads(respose[1])
    video_duration = res['entry']['media$group'][
        'media$content'][0]['duration']
    return video_duration
```

Comment: Your pseudo-code is correct. You need to use an XML parser like [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). What is the specific problem you are experiencing?

Comment: tree = ET.parse(xml) -> error Invalid argument: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/LPfnK8lSLOQ'. Do I need to specific .xml in that path or?

Answer (score 0):

getting the duration of a video from youtube is quite simple.you just need to analyze the response of the api call.
i did it with httplib2.

its better to work with json instead of xml

videoID in the request url  is the id of youtube video

```
  import httplib2
  import json

  h = httplib2.Http()
  respose = h.request("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoID?v=2&alt=json")
  res = json.loads(respose[1])
  duration = res['entry']['media$group']['media$content'][0]['duration']
```

Comment: Can you help me with implementation on my model please? Check my edited question please

Comment: @John you're getting the error because function should be above the model definition

Comment: You mean like this ? https://gist.github.com/aznnoh/27edbec4ba1834683e9d ? video_duration is not defined... I think it must take video_id first and then work with it.Given id -> url -> your code -> return duration and save it into database

Comment: Got it , I used Pafy library for this, here is the code that do what I want : https://gist.github.com/aznnoh/b6e56bbdb7ffb1cb44b3